# Would an advanced and peaceful alien race have schools?

Tags: aliens, culture, education

I am designing an alien planet which is inhabited by a peaceful advanced race and I was wondering, do aliens have schools or an education system on their planet? If so, what do you think it would be like?

Comment: It's your fictional planet, how are we supposed to come with an objective answer?

Comment: I agree with L.Dutch, it’s yoyr Aliens, not ours.

Comment: You are asking us to build your world for you. That is something you'll have to do on your own.

Comment: This question seems to be primary opinion based, and should be edited to be more clear and precise. Otherwise it may be put on hold and closed.

Comment: Before we all jump onto the down vote bandwagon, I think the OP could be referring to a particular form of advanced alien race which he/she hasn't quite identified in the question.

Comment: John, why wouldn't they have schools?  What's the purpose of the question?

Comment: @angelofdev then he needs to identify the race and its characteristics for us good folks and even then, it would still be mostly opinion based.

Comment: This question may seem opinion-based to persons with little or no knowledge of developmental psychology or education. Anything someone has no knowledge of or expertise in will appear only a matter of opinion, but they would wrong.

Comment: @a4android, developmental psychology is highly dependent on the species to which it is applied. Without any info on these peaceful advanced aliens, we can only make educated guess, which are no more than well dressed opinions.

Comment: @L.Dutch Yes but you can determine what sort of sapients would or would not have educational systems. And, on the contrary, educated guesses are better than well-dressed opinions. Also, they move any answers out of the primary opinion-based arena.

Comment: Please don't use edits to comment. Earn reputation to access that privilege instead of circumventing the site rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, for humanity, it is necessary to pass down knowledge in order for our children and descendants so that our civilization is maintained.

Most western schools use the old fashioned, sit in a desk and listen to the teacher method. You could use that method. Or, you could use a more individual method were each student is taught at their own pace. Your call

Answer (score 2):

Yes, depends on how advanced of an alien race you're referring to, like do they have an economy, transportation, military (for defence).

No, would be if they are of a hive mind type of advanced alien race where intelligence is formed by a number of alien individuals.